# Adding two numbers in unix

Tags: sh

I tried to add two numbers by below logic:

```
num=0001
newnum=`expr $num + 1`
echo $newnum
```

But it returns '2', my desired output is '0002'.

```
num=0001
newnum=`expr $num + 0001`
echo $newnum
```

I used above logic also,but no use. What is needed here to get my desired output.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which shell are you using? (type 'echo $SHELL' to find out).  Also, look at the "printf" command.

Comment: What you wrote won't work -- you can't have a space after `=`. I don't know how you're getting `2` with that code.

Comment: It is /bin/bash @rojomoke

Comment: It was a typo error, edited it. @Barmar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `printf` to print numbers with leading zeroes:

```
printf "%04d\n" $num
```

You shouldn't do arithmetic with numbers with leading zeroes, because many applications treat an initial zero as meaning that the number is octal, not decimal.

Comment: It is working..Thanks for your quick reply. This is the simple and good one!

Answer (score 1):

Use `printf`:

```
$ num=0001
$ printf "%04d" $(expr $num + 1)
0002
```

In order to assign the result to a variable, say:

```
$ newnum=$(printf "%04d" $(expr $num + 1))
$ echo $newnum
0002
```

Answer (score 0):

Numbers with leading zeros are interpreted as octal numbers. In order to treat them as decimals you need to prepend `10#` to the number. Finally, use `printf` to pad the number with zeros.

```
num=0001
newNum=$((10#$num + 1))
paddedNum=$(printf %04d $newNum)
```